# docker load no space left on device RHEL

Tags: docker

I was trying to load a saved docker image using the command `$docker load <ubuuntu_ds.tar` .

The image was created in another machine and moved to this.

It throws an error saying no space left in device. There is close to 2T space in the Machine. Here is the full log of command. Any clue how to resolve the same.

```
sh-4.2$ docker load <ubuntu.tar
0a42ee6ceccb: Loading layer 
[==================================================>]  118.8MB/118.8MB
c2af38e6b250: Loading layer 
[==================================================>]  15.87kB/15.87kB
5e95929b2798: Loading layer 
[==================================================>]  14.85kB/14.85kB
2166dba7c95b: Loading layer 
[==================================================>]  5.632kB/5.632kB
bcff331e13e3: Loading layer 
[==================================================>]  3.072kB/3.072kB
e87037031374: Loading layer 
[==================================================>]  516.8MB/516.8MB
no space left on device
```

Comment: Your "final diagnosis" should be added as an answer, not edited into the question. Accepting your own answer is permissible. See [Is it OK for users to edit the accepted answer into their question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262806) and [Add description of used solution - how?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298405) on [meta].

Comment: Final diagnosis is : The `/var` in the system was just 5 GiG which caused this problem. The solution is provided here. Used the solution from [here] (https://forums.docker.com/t/how-do-i-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory/1169) to resolve the same  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

```
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls {{.ID}})

docker system prune
```

Also remove dangling images:

```
docker images -aq -f 'dangling=true' | xargs docker rmi
```

If none of that works try:

Edit conf file
 `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf`

```
[Service]
ExecStart= 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --storage-opt dm.basesize=40GB --storage-opt dm.min_free_space=40%%
```

Restart Docker:

```
systemctl stop docker.service
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start docker.service
```

Comment: I tried the same. But still it is showing the same seeror as in the original post.

Comment: There was no images in the machine. The ubuntu container (ubuntu.tar) was copied from another machine to this particular server.

Comment: These steps helped me to diagnose the problem. The storage capability in /var was just 10 GiG.